# Why the font of one call to @Composable function is green by defalt color scheme but the other one is blue?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My current version of Android Studio is Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3. In AS *Settings/Editor/Color scheme/Compose* by defalt for color scheme "IntelliJ Light" **Calls to @Compose functions** are of **green** color(#009900). There are six such calls shown in a when block. I can’t find an explanation of why some of them are blue and not green. Is there any meaning to it?

[image: Here is a picture with example of different colored composables]

Comment: My guess: ones a function others a constructor

Comment: Is one of the Composables returning something?

Comment: @MARSK , all of them return a Unit as any of Composables must.

Comment: No it's not a 'must', for your info. Hmm, maybe some other differences like the... Like the ...  Yeah I got nothing.